# Thermodynamic calculations for irreversible processes

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

In Q5.5 of Sethna 'Entropy, Order, Parameters and Complexity', we are presented with a pressure-volume diagram for a process on a monoatomic ideal gas consisting of the following steps:

"(a) cooling at constant volume by connecting to a heat bath at $T_c$, (b) heating at constant pressure by connecting to heat bath at $T_h$, (c) compressing at constant temperature while remaining to the bath at $T_h$."

One is then expected to answer a series of T/F questions, for example:

"(T) (F) The work done per cycle has magnitude $|W | = P_0 V_0 |4 \text{log}(4) − 3|$."

As I understand it, we are expected to calculate work using standard methods, i.e. integrating the work one form $-PdV$ by pulling out the constant pressure or using the equation of state for the ideal gas. Indeed, by performing such a calculation my answer was marked correctly (I was set this question for a problem sheet).

My question is this. Given the process is clearly irreversible, as we have heat flowing from hot to cold for steps (a) and (b), how is such an integral supposed to  even make sense? I thought we were only  allowed  to perform such calculations for reversible processes, for which the intermediate states  are  all  equilibrium  states.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem, they are implicitly assuming that step 3 is done reversibly, but steps 1 and 2 are irreversible. In step 1, the irreversibility is entirely due to the heat transfer at a constant reservoir temperature different from that initially.  In step 2, the irreversibility can be partially due to the heat transfer at a constant temperature reservoir different from that initially, and partially due to the deformation at constant pressure.  In this case, it is assumed that the external pressure is held constant until the system equilibrates at the hot reservoir temperature; internally, the pressure can vary with position and time during this process step, but the force per unit area at the piston face is controlled to be constant.  The work in this irreversible step is, of course, $P_{ext}\Delta V$, where $P_{ext}$ matches the gas "pressure" at the piston face.  So, even though the work calculated for this partially irreversible cycle is the same as if the cycle were reversible (and the total heat transfer is the same), if you evaluate the entropy change for the reservoirs, it will be positive.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it, we are expected to calculate work using standard
> methods, i.e. integrating the work one form $-PdV$ by pulling out the
> constant pressure or using the equation of state for the ideal gas.

You can't use the ideal gas equation along the process path for (b) because it is not reversible due to heat transfer over a finite temperature difference. The same applies to (a). Since (b) is irreversible, the gas pressure will only equal the external pressure at the piston interface during the process. The ideal gas equation only applies to the initial and final equilibrium states for process (b) (as well as process (a)).

But it doesn't matter because work is always based on the external pressure, whether the process is reversible or not, and for a constant external pressure process it will be $P_{ext}\Delta V$.

> My question is this. Given the process is clearly irreversible, as we
> have heat flowing from hot to cold for steps (a) and (b), how is such
> an integral supposed to even make sense?

Because as stated above, work done in (b) only depends on the external pressure, and no work is done in (a). Process (c) appears to be a reversible isothermal compression based on the form of the answer. Assuming it is, the work done in (c) will be reversible.

*So in summary you have (a) a constant volume heat extraction that involves no work whether it is reversible or not, (b) a constant external pressure expansion (heat addition) where the work is $P_{ex}\Delta V$, whether it is reversible or not, and (c) an apparently reversible isothermal compression (heat extraction) where the work is reversible. So for this cycle the work done is the same whether or not processes (a) and (b) are reversible.*

On the other hand, since the overall cycle is irreversible there will be an increase in the total entropy of the thermal reservoirs, whereas for a reversible cycle the total change in entropy would be zero.

> So in other words, for step c, we are truly performing a thermodynamic
> integral because the process is reversible, but for step b, we are
> merely using that work is external pressure times change in volume,
> which is still true for an irreversible process.

I'm not sure what you mean by  "truly performing a thermodynamic integral". For both $b$ and $c$ we are performing a legitimate integral. In both cases the pressure is the external pressure. See comments below regarding your next question.

> I have one other question though. Surely it is not quite correct for
> Sethna to present a "pressure-volume" diagram for the ideal gas in the
> process as he does (it consists of a downward vertical path for step
> a, a horizontal path for step b, then a third path closing the
> triangle), because for the intermediate states of step a we can't
> define a pressure, and for the intermediate states of step b we can't
> define a volume?

Once again, the pressure used for calculating work is always the external pressure regardless of whether the process is reversible or irreversible. That applies to (a), (b), and (c).

Regarding Pv diagrams in general, there is generally no way of telling if a process is reversible or irreversible just by looking at the diagram. For one thing, a reversible process has to be carried out infinitely slowly. The Pv diagram does not indicated the time of a process.

A description of a process needs to accompany the diagram in order to determine whether or not it is reversible. If no description is given, we generally assume the process is reversible. If a process is described as irreversible then you know that the line showing the path only tells you the external pressure because the system is not in internal equilibrium. Pressure gradients exist in the system so there is no single pressure until things settle down and equilibrium is re-established.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does help, thanks very much. So in other words, for step c, we are truly performing a thermodynamic integral because the process is reversible, but for step b, we are merely using that work is external pressure times change in volume, which is still true for an irreversible process.

Comment: I have one other question though. Surely it is not quite correct for Sethna to present a "pressure-volume" diagram for the ideal gas in the process as he does (it consists of a downward vertical path for step a, a horizontal path for step b, then a third path closing the triangle), because for the intermediate states of step a we can't define a pressure, and for the intermediate states of step b we can't define a volume?

Comment: @user6314 See update to my answer responding to your comments.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I guess by 'thermodynamic integral' what I was trying to say is line integrals of the usual 1-forms, e.g. dQ, dW, dS, over curves in the state space of equilibrium states- I'm thinking of somewhat mathematical treatments of thermodynamics.

Comment: Regarding the pressure volume diagram, I should have been clearer- Sethna specifies in the question that we are directly transferring heat from hot to cold over step b. I still don't entirely see how one can make sense of a pressure volume diagram for an irreversible process, given that for the intermediate states one of the quantities might not be defined, but I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You meant step (a) didn’t  you?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @user6314 In my view, the irreversible isochoric process (step a) should be shown on the PV diagram as a dashed vertical line and not a solid line. For step (a) the external pressure is irrelevant. The pressure on the PV diagram should be the gas pressure. But for the irreversible heat transfer there is no defined equilibrium pressure, but pressure (and temperature) gradients. For that reason I believe it should not be shown as a solid vertical line.